# Background slideshow - Jquery

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm trying to create a slideshow that will run in a DIV in the background while having links on top of it.  The problem that I'm running into is that when I'm transitioning through pictures using the fadeIn and fadeOut JQuery functions, it is fading out the links as well.  Is there a way to fade only the background image?  My code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
var bgimage=new Array()
  bgimage[0] = 'bg_pic2.jpg';
  bgimage[1] = 'bg_pic3.jpg';
  bgimage[2] = 'bg_pic4.jpg';
  bgimage[3] = 'cbg_pic5.jpg';
  bgimage[4] = 'bg_pic1.jpg';  

  var abc=-1

  function t()
  {
    if (abc<bgimage.length-1)
 {
   abc++;
 }
 else
 {
   abc=0;
 } 
    document.getElementById("mainpic").style.backgroundImage = 'url("'+bgimage[abc]+'")';
 $('#mainpic').fadeIn();
 $('#mainpic').delay(3900).fadeOut();

  }  
          window.onload = load;

  function load()
  {
 $('#mainpic').hide();  
    $('#mainpic').delay(500).fadeIn();
  document.getElementById("mainpic").style.backgroundImage =     'url(css/images/bg_pic1.jpg)';
    setInterval("t()",5000); //change every 4 seconds, can be changed.
 $('#mainpic').delay(3600).fadeOut();
  }


//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" >
     <div id="mainpic" class="mainpic">  
      <div style="float:right; height: 531px; width: 20px"></div>
        <br />        
        <div class="coaches"><a href=""></a></div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />      
        <div class="hours"><a href=""></a></div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />      
        <div class="pics"><a href=""></a></div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />              
        <div class="blog"><a href=""></a></div>
      </div>          
    </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the effect you want if you put the text in a separate DIV from the image.  That way fading out the image div won't fade out the text.
The div containing the text and images should have a relative positioning with the two child divs having absolute positioning.  The text div should have a higer z-index than the image div to make sure that the text is "above" the images.

Try something like:

```
<body> 
    <div id="container" > 
     <div id="mainpic" class="mainpic" style="position:relative;">   
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 531px; width: 400px"></div> 
      <div id="text" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: z-index=1">
        <br />         
        <div class="coaches"><a href=""></a></div> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br />       
        <div class="hours"><a href=""></a></div> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br />       
        <div class="pics"><a href=""></a></div> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br />               
          <div class="blog"><a href=""></a></div> 
        </div>
      </div>           
    </div>  
</body>
```

Note that I adjusted the width of your image div. You probably want to set that to the actual width of your images.

Comment: I tried your code above and it still is not working. . . the links are still fading along with the #mainpic DIV.

Comment: Sorry my code sample didn't work out for you.  I do still think the problem is how the divs are nested and I thought that the change above would fix it.  If you have the firebug plugin for Firefox, you might want to play with it a bit to see how the DIVs are interacting.  You can even modify the CSS in 'real time' with firebug so that might help too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work in Firefox and Chrome, but IE pushed the image WAY out to the right. . .

```
<div style="width:755px; height:507px; border: #888 5px solid;">
  <div id="container" > 
   <div id="mainpic" class="mainpic" style="position: absolute"> 
   </div>        
     <div id="links" style="position: relative">
       <div style="float:right; height: 531px; width: 20px"></div>
       <br />
        <div class="coaches"><a href=""></a></div> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br />       
        <div class="hours"><a href=""></a></div> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br />       
        <div class="pics"><a href=""></a></div> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br />               
        <div class="blog"><a href=""></a></div> 
     </div>     
  </div>         
</div>
```